# Spring: AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

У меня есть 4 класса-сущности:
`Category, Company, Section, Dish`. Я настроил **relationship**, но видимо где-то ошибся. Пытался нагуглить, изучил статьи про relationship, но ошибку не могу найти, помогите пожалуйста
Category.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "categories")
public class Category {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name= "increment", strategy= "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru")
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng")
    private String titleEng;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Company> companies;

    public Category() {}

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public List<Company> getCompanies() {
        return companies;
    }

    public void setCompanies(List<Company> companies) {
        this.companies = companies;
    }
}
```

Company.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")

public class Company {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Section> sections;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Category.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private Category category;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "description", nullable = false, length = 1550)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public List<Section> getSections() {
        return sections;
    }

    public void setSections(List<Section> sections) {
        this.sections = sections;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
}
```

Section.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sections")

public class Section {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "section", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Dish> dish;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, targetEntity = Company.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "company")
    private Company company;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imageUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    public List<Dish> getDishes() {
        return dish;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    public Company getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setDish(List<Dish> dish) {
        this.dish = dish;
    }

    public void setCompany(Company company) {
        this.company = company;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Section() {

    }

}
```

Dish.class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dishes")

public class Dish {

    @ManyToOne(optional =  false, targetEntity = Section.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "section")
    private Section section;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "increment")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "increment", strategy = "increment")
    @Column(name = "id", length = 6, nullable = false)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title_ru", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleRu;

    @Column(name = "title_eng", nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String titleEng;

    @Column(name = "description_ru", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionRu;

    @Column(name = "description_eng", nullable = false, length = 500)
    private String descriptionEng;

    @Column(name = "img_url", nullable = false, length = 150)
    private String imgUrl;

    @Column(name = "weight", nullable = false, length = 5)
    private int weight;

    @JsonIgnore
    public Section getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(Section section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitleRu() {
        return titleRu;
    }

    public void setTitleRu(String titleRu) {
        this.titleRu = titleRu;
    }

    public String getTitleEng() {
        return titleEng;
    }

    public void setTitleEng(String titleEng) {
        this.titleEng = titleEng;
    }

    public String getDescriptionRu() {
        return descriptionRu;
    }

    public void setDescriptionRu(String descriptionRu) {
        this.descriptionRu = descriptionRu;
    }

    public String getDescriptionEng() {
        return descriptionEng;
    }

    public void setDescriptionEng(String descriptionEng) {
        this.descriptionEng = descriptionEng;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public int getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }

    public void setWeight(int weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }

    public Dish() {

    }

}
```

Когда я деплою программу через tomcat выходит такая ошибка в консоли:
Логи ошибки (первые 2000 символов ошибки не залил, потому что не поместилось):

```
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:346)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicService com.qoobico.remindme.server.controller.ReminderController.service; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#28ded8d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#28ded8d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'basicServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#28ded8d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#28ded8d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 60 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.qoobico.remindme.server.repository.DishesRepository com.qoobico.remindme.server.service.BasicServiceImpl.dishesRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#28ded8d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#28ded8d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dishesRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#28ded8d' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#28ded8d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545)
    ... 73 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#28ded8d': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:444)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
    ... 86 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [com/qoobico/remindme/server/config/Datasource.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 94 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
    ... 103 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Dish.category in com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories.dish
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:775)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:353)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:370)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:359)
    at com.qoobico.remindme.server.config.Datasource.entityManagerFactory(Datasource.java:44)
    at com.qoobico.remindme.server.config.Datasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$635376c6.CGLIB$entityManagerFactory$2(<generated>)
    at com.qoobico.remindme.server.config.Datasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$635376c6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$344e7b26.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:318)
    at com.qoobico.remindme.server.config.Datasource$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$635376c6.entityManagerFactory(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
    ... 104 more
```

Comment: Судя по стектрейсу сущностей больше. Добавьте в вопрос исходники класса com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories

Comment: я не понимаю почему показывает что сущностей больше, на самом деле есть всего 4 сущности, вот скрин - http://joxi.ru/1A5y08JSnjKDkA  может быть есть какие-то скрытые сущности? как это проверить?

Comment: Возможно осталась скомпилированная версия класса Categories, который был удален или переименован. Попробуйте почистить целевой каталог компилятора (не знаю как это делается в idea). Если это maven проект - то mvn clean. Для gradle - ./gradlew clean или gradle clean.

Comment: Спасибо! Благослави тебя Господь! Напиши комментарий выше как ответ, я его помечу как правильным! Целый день мучился с этой проблемой, а нужно было всего 2 класса удалить из каталога компилятора, пришлось вручную удалять эти классы из каталога, потому что idea не хотел удалять их!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по стектрейсу на рантайме в classpath есть класс сущности `com.qoobico.remindme.server.entity.Categories` со ссылкой в мапинге на класс Dish. Если класса `Categories` нет в исходниках, то возможно осталась его скомпилированная версия после удаления или переименования. Попробуйте почистить целевой каталог компилятора (не знаю как это делается в idea). Если это maven проект - то mvn clean. Для gradle - ./gradlew clean или gradle clean.